# First version of TOR with obfs4

Tags: obfs4

I have an application that I run that is security minded. It runs Tor 0.2.5.1 and i was wondering if OBFS4 was added to tor before or after this version, does anyone know?

(its daemon and runs in background so its not like i can check the drop-down.)

I have checked google and didn't see anything there and have also done a quick search on tor's website.

Comment: If your application is security minded, you should probably be running the latest version of Tor.

Answer (score 0):

`obfs4` is a distinct program.

`tor` is normally configured to launch and manage a copy of the `obfs4` program which provides a SOCKS interface for Tor to connect to a bridge over.

`obfs4` is a "Pluggable Transport", meaning it follows the [Pluggable Transport Specification](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/pt-spec.txt).

Tor 0.2.5.1 supports pluggable transports.

However if the device is "security minded", as you claim, it should not be running old and unpatched versions of Tor like 0.2.5.1. The 0.2.5.x series is on 0.2.5.16 as there have been numerous security patches since 0.2.5.1.